# Truncate na linha de uma td

Tags: html, html5

Bom dia, possuo um  css chamado truncate, que limita a exibição de uma coluna da tabela a apenas uma linha, gostaria de saber o que posso fazer para limita-lo a 2 linhas, esse método será usada em 2 colunas

CSS:

```
.truncate{
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width:2px;
  width: 90px;

 }
```

Comment: "método css"? Tá meio confuso, pode exemplificar o que quer?

Comment: Eu tenho uma coluna de uma tabela que exibe o nome de uma Escola, quero que esse nome fique em 2 linhas, e quando for muito grande fique da seguinte maneira:  1ª linha: escola maria  2ª linha: das graças... e a continação nos 3 pontos